# Python's equivalent functions to fromJSON(), unlist(), attr() of R?

Tags: python, r, json, nested

I wrote a code in R but it can't take my heavy files, so I switched to Python. But I've been looking for 3 Python's equivalent functions of R and haven't found any satisfying results.

The 3 R functions are:

```
fromJSON()
unlist()
attr()
```

OK let me show you my problem, I show you what I do and what I get in R. And now I want to do the same thing in Python.

```
json_file <- '[
  {
    "id": "haha",
    "type": "table",
    "A": "HKD",
    "B": "HKD",
    "C": "HKD",
    "V": "HKD",
    "composition": [
      {
        "id": "AO",
        "type": "panier"
      },
      {
        "id": "KK",
        "type": "basket",
        "isAutoDiv": false,
        "composition": [
          {
            "id": "600",
            "type": "apple",
            "number": 1.11
          },
          {
            "id": "605",
            "type": "peach",
            "number": 1.79
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "KL",
        "type": "basket"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "hoho",
    "type": "table",
    "composition": [
      {
        "id": "KT",
        "type": "panier"
      },
      {
        "id": "OT",
        "type": "panier"
      },
      {
        "id": "CL",
        "type": "basket",
        "isAutoDiv": false,
        "composition": [
          {
            "id": "450",
            "type": "apple"
          },
            {
            "id": "630",
            "type": "orange"
          },
          {
            "id": "023",
            "type": "orange",
            "composition": [
              {
                "id": "AOOOOOOO",
                "type": "orangejuice"
              },
              {
                "id": "VMVMVMVMV",
                "type": "orangejuice"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

Now I do this:
1:

```
nestedjson <- fromJSON(json_file)
```

I can get:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "haha"

[[1]]$type
[1] "table"

[[1]]$A
[1] "HKD"

[[1]]$B
[1] "HKD"

[[1]]$C
[1] "HKD"

[[1]]$V
[1] "HKD"

[[1]]$composition
[[1]]$composition[[1]]
[[1]]$composition[[1]]$id
[1] "AO"

[[1]]$composition[[1]]$type
[1] "panier"


[[1]]$composition[[2]]
[[1]]$composition[[2]]$id
[1] "KK"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$type
[1] "basket"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$isAutoDiv
[1] FALSE

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition
[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[1]]
[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[1]]$id
[1] "600"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[1]]$type
[1] "apple"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[1]]$number
[1] 1.11


[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[2]]
[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[2]]$id
[1] "605"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[2]]$type
[1] "peach"

[[1]]$composition[[2]]$composition[[2]]$number
[1] 1.79




[[1]]$composition[[3]]
[[1]]$composition[[3]]$id
[1] "KL"

[[1]]$composition[[3]]$type
[1] "basket"




[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "hoho"

[[2]]$type
[1] "table"

[[2]]$composition
[[2]]$composition[[1]]
[[2]]$composition[[1]]$id
[1] "KT"

[[2]]$composition[[1]]$type
[1] "panier"


[[2]]$composition[[2]]
[[2]]$composition[[2]]$id
[1] "OT"

[[2]]$composition[[2]]$type
[1] "panier"


[[2]]$composition[[3]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$id
[1] "CL"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$type
[1] "basket"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$isAutoDiv
[1] FALSE

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]$id
[1] "450"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]$type
[1] "apple"


[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]$id
[1] "630"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]$type
[1] "orange"


[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$id
[1] "023"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$type
[1] "orange"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]$id
[1] "AOOOOOOO"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[1]]$type
[1] "orangejuice"


[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]
[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]$id
[1] "VMVMVMVMV"

[[2]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[3]]$composition[[2]]$type
[1] "orangejuice"
```

Then I do this 2:

```
unnestedjson <- unlist(nestedjson)
```

I can get:

```
   id 
                                  "haha" 
                                    type 
                                 "table" 
                                       A 
                                   "HKD" 
                                       B 
                                   "HKD" 
                                       C 
                                   "HKD" 
                                       V 
                                   "HKD" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "AO" 
                        composition.type 
                                "panier" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "KK" 
                        composition.type 
                                "basket" 
                   composition.isAutoDiv 
                                 "FALSE" 
              composition.composition.id 
                                   "600" 
            composition.composition.type 
                                 "apple" 
          composition.composition.number 
                                  "1.11" 
              composition.composition.id 
                                   "605" 
            composition.composition.type 
                                 "peach" 
          composition.composition.number 
                                  "1.79" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "KL" 
                        composition.type 
                                "basket" 
                                      id 
                                  "hoho" 
                                    type 
                                 "table" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "KT" 
                        composition.type 
                                "panier" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "OT" 
                        composition.type 
                                "panier" 
                          composition.id 
                                    "CL" 
                        composition.type 
                                "basket" 
                   composition.isAutoDiv 
                                 "FALSE" 
              composition.composition.id 
                                   "450" 
            composition.composition.type 
                                 "apple" 
              composition.composition.id 
                                   "630" 
            composition.composition.type 
                                "orange" 
              composition.composition.id 
                                   "023" 
            composition.composition.type 
                                "orange" 
  composition.composition.composition.id 
                              "AOOOOOOO" 
composition.composition.composition.type 
                           "orangejuice" 
  composition.composition.composition.id 
                             "VMVMVMVMV" 
composition.composition.composition.type 
                           "orangejuice"
```

Finally I do this 3:

```
unnestednames <- attr(unnestedjson, "names")
```

I can get the results below:
And that is all I want from a Python code:
A list of names in which **the name of the attribute containing "composition." can show at which level the attribute is.**

For example, an attribute at the 2nd nested level has the name "composition.type", an attribute at the 4th nested level has the name "composition.composition.composition.id".

```
[1] "id"                                      
 [2] "type"                                    
 [3] "A"                                       
 [4] "B"                                       
 [5] "C"                                       
 [6] "V"                                       
 [7] "composition.id"                          
 [8] "composition.type"                        
 [9] "composition.id"                          
[10] "composition.type"                        
[11] "composition.isAutoDiv"                   
[12] "composition.composition.id"              
[13] "composition.composition.type"            
[14] "composition.composition.number"          
[15] "composition.composition.id"              
[16] "composition.composition.type"            
[17] "composition.composition.number"          
[18] "composition.id"                          
[19] "composition.type"                        
[20] "id"                                      
[21] "type"                                    
[22] "composition.id"                          
[23] "composition.type"                        
[24] "composition.id"                          
[25] "composition.type"                        
[26] "composition.id"                          
[27] "composition.type"                        
[28] "composition.isAutoDiv"                   
[29] "composition.composition.id"              
[30] "composition.composition.type"            
[31] "composition.composition.id"              
[32] "composition.composition.type"            
[33] "composition.composition.id"              
[34] "composition.composition.type"            
[35] "composition.composition.composition.id"  
[36] "composition.composition.composition.type"
[37] "composition.composition.composition.id"  
[38] "composition.composition.composition.type"
```

I've been looking for some Python functions that do the same things but haven't found anything. If you have any idea to do these in Python, that would solve my big problem!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is partiall. I only explained how to unlist.

For numbers we do unlist like below:

unlist numbers
 Ex:

```
aa = [1,2,3,4]  


for i in aa:  
    print(i, end="" )
```

For string we need to unlist like bleow:

```
c=["a", "ja", "ra", "ya", "ma"]  
ab= ",". join(c)   
print(ab)
```

Other way to unlist using Pd.series
ex:

```
vector = [1,2,3,4,5]  
print(pd.Series(vector))
```

Again want to convert into list:

```
square_vector = pd.Series(vector)   
print(square_vector.tolist())
```